# Зацикленная анимация

Tags: canvas, javascript, циклы

Пишу графическое приложение с помощью javascript и canvas. Нужно чтобы изображение "проплывало" по оси X через холст, полностью скрывалось за пределами холста, возвращалось "на исходную" и проплывало снова и снова и снова.

Я сделала так:

```
var X=0;

CTX.drawImage(IMG[10],X,100,100,100);

while (X<W+100)
{
 X++;
            if (X>=W+100)
     {
      X=0;
     }
}
```

Но в таком варианте оно даже запускаться отказывается, просто виснет и все.

Как сделать правильно?

Comment: Всё это происходит мгновенно, попробуйте двигать по таймеру.

Comment: и надо ещё рисовать а не только присваивать переменную.

Comment: Я правильно поняла?

var X=0;

setInterval(Animation(X,W,,CTX), 10);  
       
function Animation(X,W,CTX)
{
 if (X<W2+100)
 {
  X++;
  CTX.drawImage(IMG[10],X,100,100,100);
 }
 else
 {
  X=0;
  CTX.drawImage(IMG[10],X,100,100,100);
 } 
} 

Все равно не работает, приложение загружается, но анимации нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Пока цикл while работает, браузер никак не будет реагировать, то есть происходит попадание в бесконечный цикл без результатов. Вы правильно поняли, что надо использовать setInterval;

2) В вашем поправленном примере передаются в функцию некоторые значение, но откуда они берутся, непонятно. Я подозреваю, что внутри функции они приобретают значение undefined или постоянное значение(т.к. передаются одни и те же значения);

Посмотрите на пример, может он Вам поможет: http://jsfiddle.net/rUPJ6/

Comment: Значения берутся из той части кода, которая работает прекрасно и не имеет никакого отношения к конкретному вопросу, по этому вставлять ее я не видела смысла, и они вполне себе определенны.


Если функции не передать эти значения выдает ошибку: Uncaught ReferenceError: X is not defined

Uncaught ReferenceError: W is not defined

Uncaught ReferenceError: CTX is not defined


Переделала цикл под ваш пример - картинка есть, анимация - не работает.

Comment: В нетривиальных проблемах надо делать тогда комплексную отладку с помощью console.log() и проверять все значения на предмет ошибок: выполняется ли цикл вообще, какие значения в начале и в конце функции, как они меняются во время цикла, действительно ли переменные содержат то, что надо и т.д., таким образом локализуя ошибку. Это касается и вашего вопроса по событиям мыши. Очень сложно найти ошибку не видя перед собой полной картины и не протестировав таким образом приложение.